# Interpreting parentage in a 17th century German marriage record when the father is not mentioned

Tags: german-language, transcriptions, illegitimate, german

It's been my experience over the past year of reviewing ~500 years of marriage records from the same town that in the later 1600s through the earlier 1800s they almost always used the same rough format:

[name of groom], [his citizenship status and trade], [his father], [in later centuries, his mother's name and maiden name], and [Jgfr if she has never married] [name of bride], daughter of [name of bride's father] [from here/[name of other city]], [his citizenship status and trade], [in later centuries, her mother's name and maiden name], were married after 3 (proclaimations).  They were married by [normally the Lord Diacon] on [date] after the hour of prayer.

However, I've run into an odd case from 1806, where the father of the bride is not named.  Generally this would indicate that she was illegitimate.  I've not found a birth record for her, nor do I think I have any record of her mother.  This is the first case I've seen where the priest indicated a "hiesigen Bürgerin" in such as way that would otherwise be how they would have named the father.  Additionally, the last name of the mother does not match:

[image]

Transcription:

> 4.) Friedrich Christian Groß Taglöhners bey Fürstl er Saline, Meister Jo Wilhelm Großens, Bürgers und Zimmermanns dahier, u Annen Barbaren
> Elisabethen, gebo Preüßelin, ehelich ältester Sohn, und Jgfr Agnesen
> Burckhardtin der hiesigen Bürgerin Johannetten Zicklerin, Tochter,
> sind nach 3. mahligen öffentl Aufgeboth, den 25 ten Feb nach der
> Bethsunde von dem Hernn Diac copuliert worden.

Rough translation (formatted for readability):

> 4.) Friedrich Christian Groß,
>
> - day laborer at the Fürstlicher Saline (local saltworks),
> - son of master Johann Wilhelm Groß the citizen
>   and carpenter here, and Annen Barbaren Elisabethen, born Preüßel,
> - (he was the) eldest son by marriage,
>
> and Jgfr(au) Agnesen Burckhardtin
>
> - daughter of the local (female) citizen Johannette Zickler,
>
> were married after 3 (proclaimations). They were married by the lord deacon (clergyman
> ranked directly below a priest) on Feb 25th after the hour of prayer.

The "daughter of the local (female) citizen Johannette Zickler" bit is the part I'm stumbling on.  My best guess is that Agnes Burckhardt was an illegitimate child of Johannette Burckhardt, and that Johannette later married a man named [unknown first name] Zickler, who did not assume paternity of Agnes, so that her last name remained unchanged.

The main problem with this is that, while I have record of every Bur[c]khardt who lived in that town and surrounding area at the time, there is no (other) record of any woman named Johannette/Johanna nor Agnes(a) alive at that time in that area.  They could always have come from somewhere else, but I'm wondering if there's a better interpretation of this record than my guess.

EDIT:
Baptism entry #40 from 1787:
Note: This is a record of an illegitimate birth, so it was originally written sideways.  I've rotated it for readability.

[image]

Comment: Interesting that "eheliche" is omitted before Tochter.

Comment: The right column gives locations of the birth records of both spouses. Do these notes make sense with the books you have looked in? Could you find the birth of the groom? Which place is this?

Comment: *DOH* Wow jadepx; I'd forgotten to transcribe those, and hadn't noticed that they were on there when I looked again at the scan.  :P  Entry 40 from 1787 definitely would help shed some light here.  Let me take a look, and I'll add it here as well.

Comment: So, she was baptised Agnesa, by Johannetta Zickler, and was illegitimate.  No mention of the father, nor of the name "Burkhardt" in the baptism record.  So that raises the question, why "Agnes(a) *Burkhardt*" in the marriage record?  There's no record of another marriage in between, and "Jgfr" in this marriage record would normally indicate that it was her first marriage.

Comment: Are both spouses from the same community? If not, have you looked at engagement or marriage records from the other community? Is there a separate engagement entry? Does the name Burdhardt come up in other places?

Comment: I have no info on the spouse; the surname is not familiar for the area, however.  There are no other records, no.  The name "Burkhardt" is what drew my eye to this entry; I've been working on tracing that surname, among others, in this town across multiple centuries.